# Python-uniconvertor: error converting cdr documents

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, cdr

I am trying to use Python-uniconvertor for converting cdr documents to pdf documents. But it is giving me an error. I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
$ uniconvertor CDIP_6.cdr CDIP.pdf
Cannot list directory /home/rashmi/.uniconvertor:[Errno 2] No such      file or directory: '/home/rashmi/.uniconvertor'
ignoring it in font_path
Cannot list directory /home/rashmi/.uniconvertor:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/rashmi/.uniconvertor'
ignoring it in font_path
Cannot load plugin module cgmloader
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/uniconvertor/app/plugins/plugins.py", line 73, in load_module
desc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-    packages/uniconvertor/app/plugins/Filters/cgmloader.py", line 336, in <module>
    init.text.fontindex = fntlst.index("Times-Roman")
ValueError: 'Times-Roman' is not in list
When importing plugin cgmloader
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/plugins/plugins.py", line 147, in __call__
module = self.load_module()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/plugins/plugins.py", line 73, in load_module
desc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/plugins/Filters/cgmloader.py", line 336, in    <module>
    init.text.fontindex = fntlst.index("Times-Roman")
ValueError: 'Times-Roman' is not in list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/__init__.py", line 82, in uniconv
    doc = load.load_drawing(input_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/io/load.py", line 364, in load_drawing
    return load_drawing_from_file(file, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/io/load.py", line 325, in load_drawing_from_file
loader = info(file, filename, match)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/plugins/plugins.py", line 154, in __call__
'message':self.class_name})
app.events.skexceptions.SketchError: Cannot load filter   cgmloader.CGMLoader
```

Comment: Hi rashmiumd. I you would help the question if you explain what the uniconverter is and where you can find it (https://sourceforge.net/projects/uniconvertor/) And then also a sample file giving this error.  If you examine your stack trace you see errors about Times Roman....

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=553456#65